# How to upgrade pgAdmin 4 on windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I installed pgAdmin 4 as part of the postgres installer for Windows. pgAdmin is now telling me there is a newer version (4.8, > 4.5 which I have). However, there is no built in upgrade functionality that I can see, and when I went to download and run the pgAdmin 4 installer to upgrade, it installed itself in the wrong place, leading to problems.

At first I tried installing it to the default location (`C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4`), which was incorrect, because the previous installation (from the postgres installer) went to a different location (`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4`).

The second time, I pointed it to my existing install of postgres (`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4`), but it installed itself to a subdirectory there instead (`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\v4`), rather than upgrading the existing installation, once again yielding to duplicated installations and problems arising from that. I assume if I go download the postgres installer, it will just reinstall version 4.5 of pgAdmin, though I have not tested this.

What is the correct method for upgrading a pgAdmin instance originally installed by the postgres Windows installer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the best option is to go to `Program and files` -> Select `PostgreSQL` and "Uninstall".

Uninstaller will ask you if you want to uninstall the whole application or only individual components. Select individual components and then select `pgAdmin`.

This will uninstall `pgAdmin` from `PostgreSQL` directory.

From now, install the latest version `pgAdmin` only from [official website](https://www.pgadmin.org/) which will install it into: `C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4`

Comment: I did this and it works

Comment: What is the best option ? To go to 'Program and files' !!! From where ? From FileExplorer ?   From Parameters\Application ? From c:\Program Files' ? Can you be more explicit ? Thanks ?

Comment: @schlebe: Search for "Control Panel", go to "Programs > Programs and Features" and you get the list of your installed programs.

Comment: Or for x64 bit version (pgAdmin 4 v7.4 (released June 29, 2023)) install into: 
"C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v7".....Worked for me. Error message disappeared.

Comment: The uninstaller did not ask me if I wanted to uninstall the whole application or only individual components...

Comment: Just so everyone's clear, uninstall is a misnomer here (as it usually is with Windows uninstaller): **your server connection data isn't deleted**

Answer (score 12):

If you Download the installer from here https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.8/windows/

It should automatically install the 4.8 version in (C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4)
overwriting any existing 4.x version but keeping your server connections and setting.

In your case, the previous install was in a different place, therefore, you ended up having 2 versions.

What I suggest to you is go to control panel and uninstall from there all the versions you have. After that go to the above link, download and install the v4.8 in the default location. Every time there is a new version available just install it and let the installer install it on the default location.

Please note that your pgadmin server connections can be found in %appdata%\pgAdmin.

Note that I have personally just upgraded from v4.5 to v4.8 using this method (installing it in the default location) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: If the major version get updated eg: pgAdmin 4 v5 goes to pgAdmin v6, then it will create two separate installs. You need to uninstall the old one manually.

Comment: win11. pgadmin installer replaced old version for me, no uninstall needed i think it went from v5 to v6 but not 100% sure if it was just a minor update version

Comment: @JesseBoyd The same thing happened to me after I skipped a couple of versions and ended up at the latest, pgAmdin v8.1, in Windows 11. I noticed it on the Windows taskbar when the shortcut wouldn't work and opening search would find two instances with the same icon.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure the best approach here.
If you update directly pgadmin from: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.10/windows/ the installation goes into 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe"

Wheras the installation of the whole EnterpriseDB Installer from:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads is installed here:
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\bin\pgAdmin4.exe"

This looks like a wholly undesirable conflict? And leads to the problem identified by @Anomaly ?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone finding this post (like me), before uninstalling your current pgAdmin 4, be aware that there may be limits on compatible versions based on your version of PostgreSQL.  Following the instructions by Claudio Corchez, I removed my existing pgAdmin 4 and downloaded the latest 6.15.  When I attempted to install it, the installer informed me that this version was not compatible with my version of PostgreSQL 10.3.  So, I headed back and downloaded 4.30, which is now running.  Unfortunately, it warns me each time I run it that a newer version is available.  I just need to upgrade my entire PostgreSQL installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue previously, and had to manually select the path.

Apparently now (v. 4.25) it auto-detects the path and updates correctly.

I had to download from the [website](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/), there was no update button embedded in pgAdmin itself