# How to recover from pgAdmin 4 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

After following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461166/how-to-upgrade-pgadmin-4-on-windows), pgAdmin 4 fails to connect to the server. It pops up a window entitled `Fatal Error` with a lengthy list of environment printout followed by an even longer list of exception traces, the most relevant of which seems to be:

```
Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.008 Sec
2023-04-26 19:28:32,904: ERROR  pgadmin:    Database migration failed
2023-04-26 19:28:33,031: ERROR  pgadmin:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1964, in _exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 748, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: shared
```

There is a `Configure` button on the dialog that offers the option of changing the timeout period, or to specify a fixed port number, neither of which have any obvious positive impact.

Is there anything I can do to recover from this, or should I just reinstall PostgreSQL from the ground up? I believe I have PostgreSQL 12.3 installed.

EDIT: I uninstalled PostgreSQL and reinstalled the latest version; the issue persists :-(

Comment: Don't do anything to your PostgreSQL installation if you have problems with pgAdmin. If anything, uninstall pgAdmin, but leave PostgreSQL alone.

Comment: same problem, downloaded EDP with Post 15.4, which comes with pgAdmin 3.2! so I decided to update to 7.7, and I got the same error

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution currently is to delete a corrupted file `%APPDATA%/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db`, but you will lose all your previous config
[source](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6195#issuecomment-1527418940)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. go to `C:\Users\(your_user_name)\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin`
2. open `runtime_gonfic.json` file with any code editor
3. change `portNo: 5050` to `5432`, save file and restart pgAdmin4